# c++ linked list, insert strings

Tags: c++, list, pointers, linked-list

This is my homework: Create a linked list class which stores a list of unique (no duplicates allowed) strings in alphabetic order.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIOW2.png)

and this is what I have so far, which is not working. can anyone find the problems for me? thank you very much. the error looks like this:

```
+       std::_String_alloc<std::_String_base_types<char,std::allocator<char> > >    {_Mypair={_Myval2={_Bx={_Buf=0x0135f988 "Adam" _Ptr=0x6d616441 <Error reading characters of string.> ...} ...} } }  std::_String_alloc<std::_String_base_types<char,std::allocator<char> > >
```

my code:

```
bool LinkedList::insert(string dataInsert) { 

     //remember to use find funcion to check dupcated.
    if (find(dataInsert) != 0)
        return false;

     // build new node.
    Node* newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = dataInsert;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    //insert into empty list
    if (head == NULL) 
    {
        head = newNode;
        return true;
    }

    //insert before first item
    if (newNode->data < head->data)
    {
        newNode->next = head;
        head = newNode;
        return true;
    }

    //insert somewhere after first item
    Node* previous = head;
    while (previous->next != NULL && previous->next->data < newNode->data)
    {
        previous = previous->next;

        newNode->next = previous->next;
        previous->next = newNode;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: When posting questions about build errors, please copy-paste (as text) the *complete* output from the compiler and/or linker. Including any possible informational notes. Also please point out *where* the errors are in the code you show, for example with comments. If you ask about a crash, then run in a debugger to locate where in *your* code it happens  and point that out, together with the values of the involved variables.

Comment: And by the way, take a closer look at that loop, which isn't really a loop at all.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ok I will redo my while loop

Comment: Step through this in the debugger.  What happens if `head->next` is null?  What happens if `head->next->data` is greater than `dataInsert`?

Comment: This will be a fine implementation as far as it goes, and you should get this working first.  However, there is a performance issue, in that you scan the list twice (once to see if the element is there already, and once to find where to insert it).  If (and only if) performance is an issue, you could optimize it by searching the list just once looking for data that is >= to your new string (as at the moment), and then checking whether the value is = (in which case just return), or > (in which case insert).

Comment: If you do that, compare against `insertData` and delay creating `newNode` until you need it.  Final thought: Do write lots of tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your below `while` might have some problems because `newNode` was inserted every time when you found the next node has smaller data than `newNode`.

```
while (previous->next != NULL && previous->next->data < newNode->data)
{
   previous = previous->next;

   newNode->next = previous->next;
   previous->next = newNode;
   return true;
}
```

I think your solution is finding a position of the largest node that smaller than `newNode`. You can refer below code:

```
 while (previous->next != NULL && previous->next->data < newNode->data)
 {
    previous = previous->next;     
 }

 newNode->next = previous->next;
 previous->next = newNode;
 return true;
```